# Is there a closed-form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{|B_n|}{n!}=??$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

Is there a closed-form of

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{|B_n|}{n!}=??$$
>   where $B_n$ Bernoulli number

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to "save all Bernoulli numbers in one value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{|B_n|}{n!} = \frac{3}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|B_{2n}|}{(2n)!}= \frac{3}{2}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B_{2n}(-1)^n}{(2n)!}.$$
Since:
$$ \frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n $$
we have:
$$ \frac{z}{2}\coth\frac{z}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{e^z-1}+\frac{-z}{e^{-z}-1}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n} $$
as well as:
$$ \frac{z}{2}\cot\frac{z}{2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{B_{2n}(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$$
leading to:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{|B_n|}{n!}=\color{red}{\frac{5-\cot\frac{1}{2}}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Sure: The sign of $B_{2n}$ is $(-1)^{n+1}$, so use the generating function
$$\sum B_n \frac{z^n}{n!} = \frac{z}{e^z - 1},$$
with $z = i$.

Comment: I think your answer will be complex value

Comment: @Reery: Nope. See some of the other answers here involving $\cot$ for an explicit calculation showing that the imaginary terms vanish. (I'm also not saying that the answer is simply $i/(e^i - 1).$)

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint:

use the taylor series of $\cot(x)$

Comment: Taylor for $cot$ includes only $B_{2n}$ ...

Comment: yes I know this, but the $B_3$,$B_5$,... $=0$

Comment: that's right :-)